# Process only first x bytes of a stream, preserve stream contents

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a function that takes in a stream

```
function processStream(stream) {

}
```

Other things process this stream after the function, so it needs to be left intact.  This function only needs the first 20 bytes of a stream that could be gigabytes long in order to complete its processing.  I can get this via:

```
function processStream(stream) {
    const data = stream.read(20)

    return stream
}
```

But by consuming those 20 bytes we've changed the stream for future functions, so we have recombine it.  What's the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with `combined-streams2` to combine my streams quickly and efficiently:

```
const CombinedStream = require('combined-stream2')

function async processStream(stream) {
  const bytes = stream.read(2048)

  const original = CombinedStream.create()
  original.append(bytes)
  if (!stream._readableState.ended) {
    original.append(stream)
  }

  return original
}
```